# Replacing "adverse" with "averse" and "not adverse" with "not averse"

Tags: meaning

> 1.A. They said they were ***not adverse*** to examining proposals for modifying the lobbying law, though they [...].
>
> 1.B. They said they were ***not averse*** to examining proposals for modifying the lobbying law, though they [...]
>
> 2.A. They said they were ***adverse*** to examining proposals for modifying the lobbying law, though they [...].
>
> 2.B. They said they were ***averse*** to examining proposals for modifying the lobbying law, though they [...]

The first sentence is quoted from The New York Times while the others are its modified versions in which "adverse" is replaced by "averse", with and whitout the "not".

The questions are: Are "adeverse" and "averse" generally interchangeable? If so, how does the use of "not" influence the possibility of interchanging these words?

Answer (score 4):

*Adverse* is wrong here.

- *Averse* is said of people: it means ‘unwilling’ or ‘opposed’.

  > They were averse to considering the proposal in the current political climate.
- *Adverse* is said of circumstances: it means ‘unfavourable’ or ‘not conducive’.

  > The current political climate is adverse to the proposal's getting a hearing.

The negatives follow suit.